# Querying rows that are greater than or equal to 24 hours in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have these set of datetimes in my database, I need to query all the datetimes that are older than or equal to 24 hours.

```
2020-07-23 11:39:25
2020-07-23 11:39:53
2020-07-23 11:27:57
2020-07-23 14:33:48
2020-09-25 09:37:11
2020-09-25 09:41:57
2020-09-25 15:30:14
```

The sql script that I found was something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE `some_date` >= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

But this one returns zero.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hi, perhaps use `some_date <= now() - interval 1 day` for dates that are older than a day

Answer (score 1):

As **@IronMan**, already suggested the solution in the comment itself.

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE some_date <= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Just a tip that such date manipulation should be done on user input only, not the actual column. As if such manipulation done of column then you'll not be able to use index(if present) on that column.

So like `(some_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= NOW()` is another solution but bad one.